# How to increase data rate via bluetooth low energy communication?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have a bike trainer (Tacx Neo 2T) that supports bluetooth communication and I am reading some information such as speed of the bike via the bluetooth.
To read the information, I am using a python library (Bleak)  and there is a GATT server with Cycling speed and cadence characteristic, and I read data from this characteristic.

My problem is that I receive data in a rate of 1 second. (1 data per second). I want to know if it's possible for me as developer(programmer) to increase the data rate transition and receive faster my data?
I am new to bluetooth and network communication and I do not know if I can somehow set the speed of data transition for my bike.

I appreiciate any help and guid.

Up to know I just was able to receive data over BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) but I want now to increase the data rate so I can receive data faster.
I am wondering if there is a parameter or configuration that I can set as client( pc ) to the server (bike trainer) and tell the bike trainer to send the data faster.

Comment: It depends on your bike device implementation only. It may have hard coded notification time. Or may allow to configure it somehow.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184838/how-can-i-customize-android-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-transfer-speed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070968/how-to-improve-android-bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-throughput

Comment: Does the Tacx Neo 2T come with an official app? How is the reading speed there?

Comment: There is an app for Tacx Neo 2T called Tacx that I installed via windows store and in this app there is two means of connections ( ANT+ and Bluetooth) ,I tried both of them and inside the app the data rate isn't fast. It shows me the speed with delay between 0.5 to 1 second.

Comment: @sashoalm, I checked your links and I was trying to somehow increase the MTU size. I read somewhere that a client (my computer) can send a request to server (bike trainer tacx) and tell the server to use a maximum MTU size. but via the python library I am using, I couldn't do it so I am searching for another library. But as Mike Petrichenko said, maybe it's not possible to change it, because it's a product and hard coded by manufactory. ( Although I am very new and I don't know too much)

Comment: @Meysam Actualy MTU/PDU size does nothing with data transferring speed. I guess your device sends data with characteristic changes Notification/Indication (it is common way for GATT communication). Even you read from the characteristic the update rate is set to 1 second. But data transferring speed depends only on Connection Interval, Latency and Link Timeout. On Window platform you can change it only on Windows 11.